# jqPlot - Combination Charts: Lines in Multiple Bar Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, bar-chart, linechart

I'm trying to draw a multiple bar chart with line chart on it usint jqPlot plugin.

here is the code I'm using to draw bar chart only (without the line):

```
var s1 = [9, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var s2 = [3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var s3 = [3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var ticks = ["2014-05-05", "2014-05-06", "2014-05-07", "2014-05-08", "2014-05-09", "2014-05-10", "2014-05-11"];
    var options = {
                title: 'Graphique Statistiques Appels Entrants',
                seriesColors:['#3BAFDA', '#E9573F', '#F6BB42'],
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: ticks
                    }
                }   
            };
    $.jqplot('chartdiv', [s1, s2, s3], options);
```

The result is as expected:http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/3421/

But when I try to add a line chart on it, the result is far from what I was expeting.
here is the code:

```
var options = {
            title: 'Graphique Statistiques Appels Entrants',
            seriesColors:['#3BAFDA', '#E9573F', '#F6BB42'],
            series:[
                {renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer},       
                {          
                    xaxis: 'x2axis',          
                    yaxis: 'y2axis'      
                }
            ],
            axes: {       
                xaxis: {          
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer       
                },       
                x2axis: {          
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer       
                },       
                yaxis: {          
                    autoscale: true       
                },       
                y2axis: {          
                    autoscale: true,          
                    renderOptions: {             
                        alignTicks: true          
                    }       
                }    
            } 
        };
```

And I added another data serie for the line chart:
var s4 = [100, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0];

here is what I got

http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/3423/

Could you help me please?

Comment: Any suggestion please?